# Matching data across pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one which has authors and their texts -- there are other columns as well -- and another which has authors and their genders and disciplines.

```
DF1
====================================
author date   text   
------------------------------------
a1     2006   "Thank you for..."
a2     2007   "When I was asked..."
a3     2014   "Biology is the ..."
a2     2010   "In the intervening..."

DF2
====================================
author gender   discipline   
------------------------------------
a2     male      psychologist
a1     female    neurologist
a3     female    biologist
```

I am scrubbing through the `pandas` documentation and searching SO and other sites trying to see how I can match authors in DF1 with their genders in DF2. I don't care if I do it inplace in DF1 or if I need to create a new dataframe, so long as the new data frame has all the information in DF1 plus the additional information, gender and/or discipline, from DF2.

I don't even have the beginnings of code here -- I just finished scrubbing DF2 of all kinds of unicode errors, so I'm a bit at wit's end at this point in the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`pd.DataFrame.merge`

```
DF1.merge(DF2[['author', 'gender']], 'left')

  author  date                     text  gender
0     a1  2006       "Thank you for..."  female
1     a2  2007    "When I was asked..."    male
2     a3  2014     "Biology is the ..."  female
3     a2  2010  "In the intervening..."    male
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.Series.map`

```
d = dict(DF2[['author', 'gender']].values)
DF1.assign(gender=DF1.author.map(d))

  author  date                     text  gender
0     a1  2006       "Thank you for..."  female
1     a2  2007    "When I was asked..."    male
2     a3  2014     "Biology is the ..."  female
3     a2  2010  "In the intervening..."    male
```

*Option 2.1*
other ways to make the `d`

```
d = DF2.set_index('author').gender
DF1.assign(gender=DF1.author.map(d))

  author  date                     text  gender
0     a1  2006       "Thank you for..."  female
1     a2  2007    "When I was asked..."    male
2     a3  2014     "Biology is the ..."  female
3     a2  2010  "In the intervening..."    male
```

*Option 2.2*
other ways to make the `d`

```
d = dict(zip(DF2.author, DF2.gender))
DF1.assign(gender=DF1.author.map(d))

  author  date                     text  gender
0     a1  2006       "Thank you for..."  female
1     a2  2007    "When I was asked..."    male
2     a3  2014     "Biology is the ..."  female
3     a2  2010  "In the intervening..."    male
```

---

**Option 3**
`pd.DataFrame.join`

```
DF1.join(DF2.set_index('author').gender, on='author')

  author  date                     text  gender
0     a1  2006       "Thank you for..."  female
1     a2  2007    "When I was asked..."    male
2     a3  2014     "Biology is the ..."  female
3     a2  2010  "In the intervening..."    male
```

Comment: Great googly moogly! Three options in one answer! Let me try this with the live dataframes and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I'm upvoting you now, but I can't confirm this is the answer just yet. I'm getting `KeyError: "['author'] not in index"` on both Option 1 and 2.1. And i'm pretty sure I'm just too tired at this point in the day to see what I'm doing wrong. Thank you, thank you. I'll happily give this a go again in the morning, and bestow the check when this comes together.

Comment: That means `author` is not a column name in one of the dataframes.  This often happens when your parsing the data and you get things like `' author'` with an accidental space in the header.  Verify if this is the case with `DF1.columns` or `DF2.columns`.  You should see something like `' author'`.  If this is the case, you can correct it with `DF1.columns = DF1.columns.str.strip()`

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Here's a check. If this were Reddit, I would throw gold at your feet.

Comment: I can now also confirm, having tested all 5 of the options above, that all work with the exception of 2.1, which threw `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. This was an incredible lesson in `pandas`'s flexibility. I wish the docs were as rich as this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'author':['a1','a2','a3','a2'],
                          'date':[2006,2007,2014,2010],
                          'text':["Thank you for","when i was asked","i m the biology","in the intervening"]})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'author':['a2','a1','a3'],
                    'gender':['male','female','female'],
                    'disciple':['pyshologist','neurologist','biologist']})




print(pd.merge(df,df2, on = 'author'))
```